# How to manage "Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table" in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm facing major issue in power bi when no data found on earlier data available web resource. Due to this issue I'm not able to apply change in dashboard and advanced editor derived steps throwing an error.

> **Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table**

How to resolve the same by creating static tables headers when no data found on resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dummy table with your headers and some dummy info your power query statement. If the data sources doesn't exist then it returns the dummy table and the power query completes, but is an elegant fail. This approach by Chris Webb explains it

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/09/18/handling-data-source-errors-in-power-query/

Comment: the above like they are attaching CSV but what I'm expecting is without attaching any file we just need to mention statically header of the table if no result.